# How to complete the "Dodgeball" goal?

Tags: asphalt-7-heat

I've completed all of the career events and all of the goals in Asphalt 7 except for "Dodgeball".  The goal is:

> DODGEBALL
>
> Complete 20 Near Misses in a single event.

A "near miss", of course, is when you travel within a small distance of an oncoming car.  The problem is that in many of the events there aren't even 20 oncoming cars and there is no way to keep track of how many near misses you've already done.

Has anyone successfully completed this goal and can describe a strategy?  Ie, which event/map/car level to use? Fast or slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is enter any level (I did the Los Angeles Tier 1 level in the the final cup) and simply wait in an area that has heavy traffic. Don't worry about what place you'll get in (you'll get dead last). Wait until the cars come by, then once you pass them, turn around and go the wrong way and go along them. Turn around and repeat until you get 20 near misses.

Comment: took 13 minutes but it worked (Los Angeles/Level 1)!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for others, but one way to do it "traditionally", which should be harder to do than the one described in the other answer, is to do it in Career Cup 12, Tier 5 Rio Elimination (Race 86). Car choice is unfortunately not an option for the event as you have to use the F40.

With all stage 4 upgrades, you can do about 3 laps of the circuit within 3min 30sec of the elimination, and each lap has upto 11 oncoming cars to pass by:

- 1 bus, 1 car after the first speed boost upto the money pickups on the bridge
- 2 cars on the straight before the nitro pickups on the bridge
- 5 cars from end of bridge to docks
- 2 cars in the outside of the final turn.

Then you can either pass the cars in Adrenaline mode, or drift next to them, to have a better control on the near passes.

Maybe one could also try a Quick Race Tier 7 Moscow Elimination, since with a fully upgraded high Tier 7 car you can do a bit more than 5 laps, each lap having 6-7 oncoming cars; but I felt it to be harder to achieve, with Tier 7 cars being harder to control, and reaching the oncoming traffic on the stretch before the final corner being a bit tricky.